Writing a custom "add shadow PK" convention
I'm trying to write a convention for bulk configuration of the model. It has to add the primary key to the base class of an entity type along with some other less important things. We need this because we found the keys added by EF Core do not use the right CLR type (long instead of uint) and because we have generic entity types and do not want to configure every single concrete type as an entity separately.
But we do not get far. EF Core tells us this:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'Context'. The exception 'The entity type 'DirectoryReference<Entry_Foo>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

But we did configure them in the convention:
public class IdShadowPropertyConvention: IEntityTypeBaseTypeChangedConvention, IEntityTypeAddedConvention
{
    static IdShadowPropertyConvention()
    {
        File.Delete("efcore.log");
    }
    public void ProcessEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder builder, IConventionContext<IConventionEntityTypeBuilder> context)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"[ProcessEntityTypeAdded] Entity `{builder.Metadata.Name}`, {builder.Metadata.IsInModel}, {builder.Metadata.HasSharedClrType}, `{builder.Metadata.BaseType?.Name}`.\n");
        using var t = context.DelayConventions();
        if(builder.Metadata is { IsInModel: true, HasSharedClrType: false, BaseType: null } && !builder.Metadata.IsOwned())
        {
            var type = builder.Metadata.ClrType;
            if(type.BaseType != typeof(object))
            {
                var entity = builder;
                do
                {
                    type = type.BaseType!;
                    var baseEntity = builder.ModelBuilder.Metadata.FindEntityType(type)?.Builder ?? builder.ModelBuilder.Entity(type)!;
                    if(!entity.Metadata.HasSharedClrType && !entity.Metadata.IsOwned())
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tSet a new base type (transitive): `{entity.Metadata.Name}` => `{baseEntity.Metadata.Name}`.\n");
                        _ = entity.HasBaseType(baseEntity.Metadata);
                    }
                    entity = baseEntity;
                }
                while(type.BaseType != typeof(object));
            }
            IConventionKeyBuilder? pk1 = null;
            {
                var baseEntity = builder.ModelBuilder.Entity(type);
                File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tBase type: {type.ShortDisplayName()}, `{baseEntity?.Metadata.HasSharedClrType}`, `{baseEntity?.Metadata.IsKeyless}`.\n");
                if(baseEntity == builder)
                {
                    if(baseEntity.Metadata is { HasSharedClrType: false } meta)
                    {
                        if(!baseEntity.Metadata.IsKeyless)
                        {
                            var prop = baseEntity.Property(typeof(uint), "Id");
                            File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tAdded an ID property: `{prop}`.\n");
                            var pk = prop is null ? baseEntity.PrimaryKey(["Id"]) : baseEntity.PrimaryKey([prop.Metadata]);
                            pk1 = pk;
                            File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tAdded a primary key: `{pk?.Metadata.GetName()}`.\n");
                        }
                        _ = baseEntity.UseMappingStrategy(RelationalAnnotationNames.TphMappingStrategy)?.HasDiscriminator();
                        File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tConfigured as a base type.\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            _ = builder.Property(typeof(uint), "RowVersion")?.ValueGenerated(ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate)?.IsConcurrencyToken(true);
            var pk2 = builder.Metadata.FindDeclaredPrimaryKey();
            File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tPKs: `{pk1?.Metadata.Properties.Select((p) => p.Name).Join(", ")}`, `{pk2?.Properties.Select((p) => p.Name).Join(", ")}`.\n");
        }
    }

    public void ProcessEntityTypeBaseTypeChanged(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, IConventionEntityType? newBaseType, IConventionEntityType? oldBaseType, IConventionContext<IConventionEntityType> context)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"[ProcessEntityTypeBaseTypeChanged] Entity `{entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.Name}`, {entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.IsInModel}, {entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.HasSharedClrType}, BT: `{entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.BaseType?.Name}`, OT: `{oldBaseType?.Name}`, NT: {newBaseType?.Name}`, OBT: `{oldBaseType?.BaseType?.Name}`, NBT: `{newBaseType?.BaseType?.Name}`.\n");
        
        if(newBaseType?.IsInModel is true)
        {
            var type = newBaseType;
            while(type.BaseType is not null)
            {
                type = type.BaseType;
            }
            File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tBase type: {type.Name}, `{type.HasSharedClrType}`, `{type.IsKeyless}`.\n");
            if(type.BaseType is null)
            {
                if(!type.IsKeyless)
                {
                    var prop = type.Builder.Property(typeof(uint), "Id");
                    File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tAdded an ID property: `{prop}`.\n");
                    var pk = prop is null ? type.Builder.PrimaryKey(["Id"]) : type.Builder.PrimaryKey([prop.Metadata]);
                    File.AppendAllText("efcore.log", $"\tAdded a primary key: `{pk?.Metadata.GetName()}`.\n");
                }
                _ = type.Builder.Property(typeof(uint), "RowVersion")?.ValueGenerated(ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate)?.IsConcurrencyToken(true);
                _ = type.Builder.UseMappingStrategy(RelationalAnnotationNames.TphMappingStrategy)?.HasDiscriminator();
            }
        }
    }
}

Exploring the resulting log, we see these relevant parts:
[ProcessEntityTypeAdded] Entity `DirectoryReference<Entry_Foo>`, True, False, ``.
    Set a new base type (transitive): `DirectoryReference<Entry_Foo>` => `DirectoryReference<Directory, Entry_Foo>`.
    Base type: DirectoryReference<Directory, Entry_Foo>, `False`, `False`.
    PKs: ``, ``.
[ProcessEntityTypeAdded] Entity `DirectoryReference<Directory, Entry_Foo>`, True, False, ``.
    Base type: DirectoryReference<Directory, Entry_Foo>, `False`, `False`.
    Added an ID property: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalPropertyBuilder`.
    Added a primary key: `PK_directory_reference_directory_entry_foo`.
    Configured as a base type.
    PKs: `Id`, `Id`.
[ProcessEntityTypeBaseTypeChanged] Entity `DirectoryReference<Entry_Foo>`, True, False, BT: `DirectoryReference<Directory, Entry_Foo>`, OT: ``, NT: `DirectoryReference<Directory, Entry_Foo>`, OBT: ``, NBT: ``.
    Base type: DirectoryReference<Directory, Entry_Foo>, `False`, `False`.
    Added an ID property: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalPropertyBuilder`.
    Added a primary key: `PK_directory_reference_directory_entry_foo`.
[ProcessEntityTypeBaseTypeChanged] Entity `DirectoryReference<Entry_Foo>`, True, False, BT: ``, OT: `DirectoryReference<Directory, Entry_Foo>`, NT: ``, OBT: ``, NBT: ``.

Apparently something in EF Core overrode our configuration and reset the base type of the entity to nothing. We tried to move the base type changing code to a model finalizing convention, but by then FKs are already in place and don't allow changing the base type anymore, and it doesn't look like it's easy to retarget them to the base type.
How can we prevent EF Core from overriding our convention like that?

I resolved this issue by passing the fromDataAnnotation argument the true value in every call that has it, and it appears that subsequent configuration respects my changes then, although ultimately I feel like this is a gross hack and we better rewrite this w/o using conventions as a bulk configuration solution in order to avoid doing it this way.
